# How to connect to MS SQL Server 2016 from PHP 7

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm attempting to insert rows in table in a database hosted in MS SQL Server 2016 installed in my local computer. 
Here is my snippet `$dbc = mssql_connect('MwangiCJ-PC/mwangi','sqluser','xxxx','mydb');`

I have tried out the answer from 
[mssql_connect() with PHP5 and MSSQL2012 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282936/mssql-connect-with-php5-and-mssql2012-express) but I still get the error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()`

When i run a simple `phpinfo()` I can see that I already have both **sqlsrv** and **pdo_sqlsrv** available.

Am I missing anything else? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: The sqlsrv extension by Microsoft has nothing to do with the mssql_connection() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php):

> **Warning**
>   This function was **REMOVED** in PHP 7.0.0.
>   Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [`PDO::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)
> - [`sqlsrv_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)
> - [`odbc_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php)

Comment: Thank you for the insight. `sqlsrv_connect()` worked correctly